# Extract block from CSS by Regular expression or any other method?

Tags: python, regex

I have to **extract text** between `/*Custom-D Start*/` and `/*Custom-D End*/`, And there maybe spaces after `/*` and maybe spaces before `*/`

I did this in Two Steps:

1. **Regular Expression** to extract start and end text.
2. **String find** method to get text between start and end text.

**Following is my code:**

```
data ="""/* Highlighting edits text on TIB ONLY and NOT ON PDF Output. 
   .main-igp selector makes this style apply only for TIB.  */
.main-igp .edit1 {color: rgb(235, 127, 36)}
.main-igp .edit2 {color: rgb(0, 0, 180);}
/*Custom-D Start     */
.main-igp .edit3 {color: rgb(0, 180, 180);}
.main-igp .edit6 {color: rgb(200, 200, 0);}
/* Custom-D End */
/* Production Note ===== */
p.production-note-rw {
    display: none;}
/* Production Note END ===== */"""


def extractCustomD():
    """ Extract Custom-D block from a CSS data.
        Starting text is /*Custom-D Start*/

        and ending text is /*Custom-D End*/
        There are may be space after /* and also before */  
    """
    import re
    try:
        start_text = re.findall("/\* *Custom-D Start *\*", data)[0]
        end_text = re.findall("/\* *Custom-D End *\*", data)[0]
    except IndexError:
        return ""
    return data[data.find(start_text)+len(start_text):data.find(end_text)]
```

**We can extract target content from regular expression? or there is any other way to do this?**

**Edit:** Following is working for me

```
>>> re.findall("/\* *Custom-D Start *\*/([\s\S]*)/\* Custom-D End \*/", data)
['\n.main-igp .edit3 {color: rgb(0, 180, 180);}\n.main-igp .edit6 {color: rgb(200, 200, 0);}\n']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you just extract `/*Custom-D Start     */` and `/* Custom-D End */` substrings. However, you need text between them.

You can just use one regex expression to extract that substring:

```
/\* *Custom-D Start *\*/\s*(.*?)/\* *Custom-D End *\*/
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ6bL4/2). Use it with the `re.S` modifier.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pYJJQB):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'/\* *Custom-D Start *\*/\s*(.*?)/\* *Custom-D End *\*/', re.DOTALL)
test_str = "/* Highlighting edits text on TIB ONLY and NOT ON PDF Output. \n   .main-igp selector makes this style apply only for TIB.  */\n.main-igp .edit1 {color: rgb(235, 127, 36)}\n.main-igp .edit2 {color: rgb(0, 0, 180);}\n/*Custom-D Start     */\n.main-igp .edit3 {color: rgb(0, 180, 180);}\n.main-igp .edit6 {color: rgb(200, 200, 0);}\n/* Custom-D End */\n/* Production Note ===== */\np.production-note-rw {\n    display: none;}\n/* Production Note END ===== */"
m = p.search(test_str)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Note that you can unroll the lazy dot matching to

```
/\* *Custom-D Start *\*/\s*([^/]*(?:/(?!\* *Custom-D End *\*/)[^/]*)*)
```

[This version](https://regex101.com/r/nQ6bL4/3) is faster than the one with lazy dot matching.